# EJBs - Architectural issue

Tags: multithreading, architecture, singleton, ejb-3.1, stateful

I'm currently writing a new EJB application which basically is supposed to receive messages from a web service and launch a downloading process based on this message content. This application will run on Glassfish 3.1.1.

My first idea was to create a singleton bean that would read the messages from the web service and use a stateful session bean to initiate and handle the download itself. I need to use stateful beans because I need to have a convertational state between my singleton and stateful bean (download status, etc.)

The "problem" is if I receive several messages from the web service I'm supposed to start several downloads in parallel, each download with its own context of course. How am I supposed to achieve this as if I invoke a stateful session bean from my singleton I'll always get the same bean, correct? The only solution I see is to use threads that would be created and launched from my singleton but this is not permitted by EJB specification...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want a stateful session bean here. The point of a stateful bean is that that maintains state in the scope of a session, which is a relationship with a particular client. In your case, there isn't one download per client (are there even any clients?), which means that this is not an appropriate scope.

If you just want multiple threads, use a stateless bean with an [@Asynchronous](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html) method. You would probably have to handle status updates using a callback to the singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a singleton bean here? Is just stateful session bean is not good enough? You want simultaneous downloads, you want statefulness, so why to use singleton? Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Hi Mark! The singleton would be the "entry point" of the application and is responsible for managing all the downloads i.e. checking the download statuses of each bean, sending those statuses via web service, interrupt/cancel all the downloads etc. Does it answer your question? Do you see another way to proceed? Regards

Comment: yes, I see, but it still doesn't convince me that you need a singleton here. I mean, let the SFSB manage the interconnection with single client, download/cancel/get status and so on. Why do you need to "centralize" this?

Comment: Because (in my opinion) I need to centralize. Because orders like cancel/interrupt download are coming from the WS for instance. So I need to be able to identify which SFSB I need to interrupt/cancel... Is that clearer?